# GraphQl Union input types

Tags: graphql, hotchocolate

In HotChocolate I have a query type like so

```cs
// QueryType.cs
public Task<ContentCategory> FilterContentAsync(string categoryCode, ICollection<Filter> filters, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
            => ...;

// Filter.cs
public abstract class Filter
{
    public string Type { get;set; }
}

// BooleanFilter.cs
public class BooleanFilter : Filter
{
    public bool IsTrue { get; set; }
}

// NumberRangeFilter.cs
public class NumberRangeFilter : Filter
{
    public int Min { get; set; }

    public int Max { get; set; }
}
```

when I run the application I get the following error

`` 1. Unable to infer or resolve a schema type from the type reference `Input: Filter`. ``

Is the following query supported:

```
filterContent (categoryCode: "All", filters: [{type: "boolean", isTrue: true}, {type: "numberrange", min: 10, max: 60}]) {
  id
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems that this is not implemented currently.

Here is [an issue in hotchocolate repository](https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/issues/1880). Currently (Jul 2021) it is open and have "backlog" label, so I can assume that input unions are not implemented yet.

And here is [a tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/michael_staib/status/1400484456985772035) of one of developers of hotChocolate, where he says

> We are implementing the #graphql oneof spec proposal for Hot Chocolate
> 12... let the input unions come :)

By the way there is another link to [discussion](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/blob/main/rfcs/InputUnion.md) about possible implementations for input union problem. So according to this, there is 7 various ideas how to change the spec, 1 winner (the 7th option) and no one single link to possible implementations.

Comment: Continuation. HC team says that they wouldn't implement this feature for now, because this desicion is not part of spec. But I have an idea, how to implement this by myself. In short, use ParseLiteral override method in InputObjectType class to detect real inheritor's type, plus disable validation of input parameters ValueVisitor. Use reflection. Please see more detailed description in [my comment](https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/issues/1880#issuecomment-882380819)